# how can i make items repeat again if i arrive the end of list

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following

```
  ListView.builder(
   controller: controller,
   itemCount: 50, 
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
   return Text('hello world');
   },
    )
```

now when i scroll to last index it stop scroll anymore .. but how can i force it to keep scroll with same items that i passed through like following

```
1
2
3
4
etc .. 50

keep scroll 
1
2
3
4
etc .. 50

and so
```

what i am doing now is adding others same 50 items but it not good idea

how could i make it auto repeat without End . without to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply leave out the `itemCount` and in the itemBuilder you could modulo 50 the index to have them repeat every 50. For example:

```
ListView.builder(
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    index = index % 50;
    return Text('hello world $index');
  },
)
```

Comment: thanks @ivo .. you make everything easy like always .. you hit what i want exactly .. but i have question here .. in this case : does we have 50 index in memory forever right ?

Comment: and what if i must use itemCount ? because it get it's items from server !